# Photoshop 24 bit image creation Issue

Tags: photoshop

How to create 24 bit image in Photoshop ?

there is option of 8 16 and 32 only
How to create 24 bit image.

Actually i have to create the landing page on play.google.com which supports Icon of 32 bit and right side information page of 24 bit. THen how can i create 24bit page in Photoshop?

Kindly suggest me some links or tutorials. THank you.

Answer (score 2):

32 bits means that there is an alpha layer, 24 bits means there is just red green and blue. Remove the alpha or save as a format that does not allow alpha and you should have 24bit.